# Is there a faster and better way to do this mysql query?

Tags: mysql

Lets assume i have two tables. Item, and Storage.
There is a relation between them by item id.
What i want is to list every item, that has no relation found in Storage
I have a hunch that my statement could be a lot simpler than this:

```
SELECT item.name,storage.stuff 
FROM item 
LEFT JOIN storage ON storage.item_id=item.id 
WHERE storage.stuff IS NULL 
GROUP BY item.id
```

Is there a way to replace LEFT JOIN to a different one so i return the item where nothing to join ?
(i actually want to keep the returning of the stuff field even if it is always NULL, because i have a query function that is serving clientside over ajax with a lot of ways to list the items, and i dont want to check there whether that field is exists or not, neither in the fetching part)

```
Table Item
id     name
1       a
2       b
3       c
4       d

Table Storage
item_id      stuff
1             this
1             that
2             this
```

Desired result:

```
item_id     item_name     stuff
   3           c           NULL
   4           d           NULL
```

Comment: yes there is a much better way because your current query is invalid ANSI GROUP BY SQL..

Comment: 'Is there a way to replace LEFT JOIN' not in mysql which does not have intersect/except (sqlserver) or the intersect/minus operators(oracle)

Comment: Well @P.Salmon in MySQL you can simulate SQL intersect with a DISTINCT INNER JOIN i assume and SQL except/minus  with a DISTINCT excluding LEFT JOIN i assume?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `Group By` in the query, as you are fetching the cases where there is no match in the `storage` table. Your `Group BY` is not valid ANSI SQL either, as non-aggregated columns / non-group-by columns are being fetched in the `Select` clause.

```
SELECT item.id, item.name, storage.stuff 
FROM item 
LEFT JOIN storage ON storage.item_id=item.id 
WHERE storage.stuff IS NULL
```

Comment: xdxd i must be very tired. At least i felt im doing something very stupid. Thank you !

Comment: @Ninet9 Please see: [How to accept an answer for closure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). You get points for it as well. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There are more methodes for this..

**LEFT JOIN method**

**Query**

```
SELECT
    Item.id
  , Item.name
  , Storage.stuff 
FROM
  Item 
LEFT JOIN
  Storage
ON
  Storage.item_id = Item.id 
WHERE
  Storage.stuff IS NULL
```

**NOT EXISTS method**

**Query**

```
SELECT
   Item.id
 , Item.name
 , NULL AS stuff
FROM 
 Item
WHERE
 NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 
   1
  FROM 
   Storage
  WHERE 
   Storage.item_id = Item.id
)
```

**NOT IN method**

**Query**

```
SELECT
   Item.id
 , Item.name
 , NULL AS stuff
FROM 
 Item
WHERE
 Item.id NOT IN (
    SELECT 
     Storage.item_id
    FROM 
     Storage
    WHERE 
      Storage.item_id = Item.id     
 )
```

see demo https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/phKyPgvGJpZ5x1Lj6sisCd/0